# How do I redirect a POST request and pass on the post data in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I want a post request to be automatically redirected to another url passing on the post data in sails.js. How would I do this?

In another way:
How do I create two POST routes which do the same thing without repeating myself? If I POST to user it should do the same thing as if I would POST the same stuff to signup.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/99966

Comment: To put it this way: How do I create two POST routes which do the same thing without repeating myself? If I POST to user it should do the same thing as if I would POST the same stuff to signup.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Sails, but it seems to me that you can point both routes to the same controller method.

Comment: The problem is that there are no methods in the controller file that I generated. I guess there is some kind of prebuilt method in sails to handle standard POST requests with a defined model.

Comment: Yeah, there are. Check this out: http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/blueprint-api. Different types of HTTP requests correspond to certain predefined controller actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the controller action you want by changing your routes.js file.

config/routes.js

```
module.exports.routes = {
  'POST /user': 'ControllerName.controllerAction'
}
```

In the above, replace ControllerName and controllerAction with the values you need.

Comment: This is what I got so far. Now I'm trying to find out what is the right controllerName.controllerAction for a standard POST from the blueprints.

Comment: That would be `ControllerName.create`, then.